# Aligning a button over a fullscreen image

Tags: html, css

I need help aligning my button to the middle (horizontally and vertically) of my screen. The button is over an image. I know there are similar questions like this on here, but I tried every advice and nothing seemed to work. I think it might be because my button is on top of an image that is at 100% in width and height, in other words, the image is a fullscreen image that takes up the whole page.

My button is at the top left corner of the screen.

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url("space.jpg");
}

.button {
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>

<img src="space.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:

- **Create** a `<div>` with `fixed dimensions` and add your **background** to it.
- **Adjust the size** of the `<div>` according to your needs.
- **Put your button inside** that `<div>`
- **Position the button inside** the `<div>` and give it `position:absolute` - in relation to its parent
- Use the `transform`property as well as `top / left / right / bottom`

```css
/* relevant starts here CSS */

.mycontent {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%
}
.button {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 0 .6em;
  color: #000;
  opacity: .6;
}
.button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topcontent {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 2560px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url(http://supersocl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/2560X1440-Wallpaper-Elegant-6G0.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.othercontent {
  background: #010101;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
}

/* irrelevant starts here CSS */

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #999;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mycontent">
    <div class="topcontent">
      <button class="button">Menu</button>
    </div>
    <div class="othercontent">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>

      <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
        ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>

      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

      <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
        assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et vo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using CSS3 ***flex-box*** concept.

**absolute center property**

- set parent (here it's wrapper): `display:flex;`
- then set child (here it's button): `margin:auto;`

It will be positioned on ***absolute center***. I've added the snippet below.

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.button {
  width:100px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! :). Mind explaining what I was doing wrong initially? Also how do I make my sentence span across the button and not line break? (e.g.:):  https://gyazo.com/fe41c1c67fade0779020112fdd71262a

Comment: @mdlz don't forget to tick if it's useful,in your code you have **margin:auto;**,but most time it makes your button horizontally centered but not vertically

Comment: I can't tick it yet, I don't have my website up. I'm just running the code from Sublime Text

Answer (score 0):

please add this code into your css :

```
button {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it will work for you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/800/400/");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
}

.button {
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

button{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```